# How is the function $g: \mathbb{R}_L \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x)=x\,$continuous?

Tags: general-topology

$\mathbb{R}_L$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are the lower limit and standard topologies on $\mathbb{R}$. If $(a, b)$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ then it's inverse, also $(a, b)$, isn't open in $\mathbb{R}_L$ because the lower limit topology is generated by the basis comprising of the semi-open intervals, $[a, b)$. I'm asking this question because in one example in James Munkres' Topology, the author writes that $(a, b)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}_L$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write $(a,b)$ as a union of sets of the form $[c,d)$.

Answer (score 3):

$(a,b) = \displaystyle\bigcup_{c \in (a,b)}[ c, b)$.

Answer (score 0):

An infinite union of open sets is open. You'll need an infinite union of intervals $[x,y)$ to get an open interval $(a,b)$, otherwise your intuition was correct that no finite union will work.